# Perfect-scrollbar not working in window.load

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am using jQuery [perfect-scrollbar](http://www.yuiazu.net/perfect-scrollbar/) to my web application. I have called perfect-scrollbar in window.load like this

```
$(window).load(function () {
        $('#Demo').perfectScrollbar();
    });
```

It works for the first time after running the code. But when i refresh the page again, it is not showing up even though the window.load function is fired.

Can you please tell me what is going wrong?

i have even tried calling like this

```
$(function() {
    $('#Demo').perfectScrollbar();
});
```

This is my sample Html. I am using the same structure.

```
         <ul>
            <li>
                <div id="Demo" style="position: relative; width: 290px; height: 600px; overflow: hidden;">
                    <div id="myTree">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a id="A1"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a id="A2"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a id="A3"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a id="A4"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a id="A5"></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I am also using [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) like this and i am trying to apply scroll for the tree

```
$("#myTree").jstree(
            {
                "themes": { "theme": "apple", "dots": false, "icons": true },
                "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "ui", "contextmenu"],
                "contextmenu": {// for context text menu
                    show_at_node: false, items: CustomContextMenu 
                }
            })
```

Comment: Please share your html. Otherwise we can be of very little help.

Comment: i have added a structure of my html. Please check. Thanks

Comment: any error in your console?

Comment: No. as i said it loads perfectly for the first time. But not showing up when i refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution to this question. We have to call the prefect scroll bar like this and it worked.

```
$("#myTree").bind('loaded.jstree', function (e, data) {
       $('#Demo').perfectScrollbar();
    }).jstree(
            {
                "themes": { "theme": "apple", "dots": false, "icons": true },
                "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "ui", "contextmenu"],
                "contextmenu": {// for context text menu
                    show_at_node: false, items: CustomContextMenu 
                }
       });
```

loaded.jstree will be loaded after the jsTree is fully loaded.

Thanks